# How to run python invoke within python code

Tags: python, invoke

I am trying to write up some python code to automate some stuff, and would like to install some ruby gems during the execution.

I am reading up [Invoke](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/index.html)

I tried using cli api which documented [here](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/concepts/cli.html), and this is how I am trying to run it:

```
import invoke
invoke.cli.parse(*args, **kwargs)
```

but getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cli'
```

Comment: You can also use subprocess.call as described [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invoke.cli` is probably a submodule of `invoke` which doesn't get imported by default.  Try:

```
import invoke.cli
```

---

Edit:  As I suspected, taking a look at [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/blob/master/invoke/__init__.py) and the [package organization](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/tree/master/invoke) confirms my suspicions.  `cli` is a submodule that you need to import explicitly.